# OR-Tools optimization eith CP-Sat

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I'm solving an optimization problem in python with OR-Tools / CP-sat solver. I'm using a file that takes some hours to reach optimal solution. Is there any way of seeing in the terminal how the process is going, like the best solution found so far, the elapsed time, etc...? I know that with cplex solver we can see this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add `log_search_progress:true` to the parameters.

Second, a good way to speed solving it to use multiple workers. This is done by using the `num_search_workers:XXX` parameter. If you have a decent machine, XXX=8 is good. If you have a beefier machine, you can try XXX=12 or 16 (or more).